# SSIS Dataflow failed with SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm doing a simple dataflow task: copy one table to another on SQL Server. My dataflow is working well on Visual Studio but failed while executing it.

Error:

[image]

I tried to look this error on internet and many went out but here is the configuration:

- SQL Agent is executed by user with proper rights
- This user can read/write table
- no encryption
- tested with 32 and 64bit connexion

My configuration:

- Win 2016 Server
- SQL Server 13
- Visual Studio 2015

Something I tried:
On my package the connection is a project connection, but when I use a local package connection embedded in the package, the dataflow is working well with SQL agent.

Looks like a project connection isn't deployable, but only package. Anyway, the issue look like it's because I'm using a project connection and not a embedded connection. I'll prefer use a project connection. It's more easy for the dev.

Any ideas?

After some exchanges, I added the Configuration Parameter : DelayValidation=True on Dataflow Task + Connection and the message are a bit different :

[image]

Comment: The error is saying that the validation failed. This likely means the definition of the object did not meet what was defined in the dataflow, or your referencing a dynamic file location, and the variable with the location of said file has not been set yet and `DelayValidation` on the source has not been set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This is very known issue of `SSIS` , please open `SSIS package` and select task>Right click and go to property> and set `Delay Validation= TRUE` for those task in which you are making connection with source and destination,this issue won't come again.

Comment: It's not an "issue", it's by design... If you have a task in SSIS to read from a file, and that file doesn't exist when the package starts, of course it's going to it's going to fail by default.

Comment: Select all the connection manage and go to property and set the delay validation = True and then build the package and again deploy the package ,and check it won't be there.

Comment: I did this on the Dataflow task : Delay Validation = True and on the connection, still same issue

Comment: have you save your package and deployed it from where you are calling in job?

Comment: but from your snapshot ,it is clearly visible that validation failed at OLE DB Destination , please check in the job whether all the parameter is passed or not..

Comment: there is no parameter in the dataflow, it's only a copy from a table to another onnthe same sql server instance where the ssis catalog and tables are.

Comment: do you know why the dataflow is working properly if I use an embeded connexion instead of a project connexion ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was dummy as usual.

I didn't deployed the project connection, but it's not abvious because to deploy a project connexion the entire project has to be deploy ... we can't just deploy a single connection.